# Swift 4: Cannot assign value of type '(Void) -> Void' to type '(() -> Void)?'

Tags: swift, promisekit

I'm a noob in the Swift-Universe, but I have to get the app running ;) 
It would be great if you help me to find a solution. Thanks a lot in advance.

The Problem occurs after upgrading to newer version of X-Code (Version 9.4.1) and Swift 4.

```swift
private var stoppedSuccessfully: (() -> Void)?

func stopRecording() -> Promise<Void> {

    return Promise { success, _ in

        self.stoppedSuccessfully = success // The error occors here: Cannot assign value of type '(Void) -> Void' to type '(() -> Void)?'


        if WCSession.default.isReachable {
            logger.info("Watch is reachable - Send Stop recording message.")
            let command = RecordingCommand.stop

            self.sendMessage(command, EvomoWatchConnectivityCore.WatchConnectivityCoreMethod.transferUserInfo,
                             nil, nil)

            // Create a Timeout
            let timeoutDelay: Double = 15

            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + timeoutDelay) {

                if self.stoppedSuccessfully != nil {
                    self.logger.warning("### Stopped waiting for Apple Watch recording by Timeout!")
                    success(Void())
                    self.stoppedSuccessfully = nil
                }

            }

            return
        }

        success(Void())
        self.stoppedSuccessfully = nil

    }

}

// In a other part of the code:
self.stoppedSuccessfully?()
self.stoppedSuccessfully = nil
```

Comment: Why you storing success block in a variable?

Comment: I don't wrote this code. So I can't answer your question.

Comment: I think you should update the library to swift 4 too(something that contains `Promise`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change the type of `stoppedSuccessfully` from `(() -> Void)?` to `((Void) -> Void)?`:

```
private var stoppedSuccessfully: ((Void) -> Void)?
```

Because, when you use `Promise<T>`, the closure type passed to `success` is of type `(T)->Void`. In your code, you are using `Promise<Void>`, so the type of `success` is `(Void)->Void`, not `()->Void`.

Thus, your `stoppedSuccessfully` should be declared as `Optional<(Void)->Void>`, which is equivalent to `((Void)->Void)?`.

---

And to call the closure of type `(Void)->Void`, you need to pass one argument of type `Void`. There's a literal notation of type `Void`, it's `()`, an empty tuple.

So, you can replace all `success(Void())`s to simply `success(())`.

And you can invoke `stoppedSuccessfully` in the similar manner:

```
// In a other part of the code:
self.stoppedSuccessfully?(())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That works fine! The answer of @Prashant also works but this solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use `Void`  use simply `stoppedSuccessfully: ((Void) -> ())?`  and call it with

```
 let obj:Void = Void()
 stoppedSuccessfully?(obj)
```

I don't understand why you have used `stoppedSuccessfully` it is un necessarily   assigned from   `success`  which will never been `nil` so Don't think your condition `if self.stoppedSuccessfully != nil` will fail

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I change the variable declaration as you mentioned. X-Code returns following error message on the "self.stoppedSuccessfully = success" line: Cannot assign value of type '(Void) -> Void' to type '(() -> ())?'.

I don't wrote this code. So I don't know if the condition will fail. But I know that the code worked before in Swift 3.

Comment: @JayUU check stoppedSuccessfully: ((Void) -> ())?

Comment: This solve the error in "self.stoppedSuccessfully = success" line but create a new error in the "self.stoppedSuccessfully?()" line. -> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Comment: @JayUU This is not right way but it will work `let obj:Void = Void()
        stoppedSuccessfully?(obj)`

Comment: You are the man!!! It's working. Thanks a lot! If you change/extend your answer, I can mark it as solved ...

Comment: @JayUU Glad that it worked for you now you can accept my answer

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't accept your answer, but @OOPers solution is cleaner. Neverless thanks a lot for your effort.